# How to format scientific notation with 1 digit after the decimal place in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, string-formatting

I have tried `sprintf("%.1e", x)` but that gives me `6.3000e-16`. How can I cut off the zeros and display just `6.3e-16`? I am also displaying the numbers in a table.

EDIT: So now it is correctly display some numbers, but others aren't displayed in scientific notation at all. I am using R2018a.

Here is the code I am using

```
n       = zeros(19,1);
a       = zeros(19,1);
b       = zeros(19,1);
c       = zeros(19,1);
d       = zeros(19,1);

format short
for i = 2:20
    w = 1/(2000 * i);
    x = 1/(1000 * i);
    y = 1/(50 * i);
    z = 1/(20 * i);
    n(i-1)          = sprintf("%d", i);
    a(i-1)          = sprintf("%.1e", w);
    b(i-1)          = sprintf("%.1e", x);
    c(i-1)          = sprintf("%.1e", y);
    d(i-1)          = sprintf("%.1e", z);
end

table(  n, a, b, c, d )
```

and here is the output:

```
  19×5 table
    n        a          b         c         d   
    __    _______    _______    ______    ______
     2    0.00025     0.0005      0.01     0.025
     3    0.00017    0.00033    0.0067     0.017
     4    0.00013    0.00025     0.005     0.013
     5     0.0001     0.0002     0.004      0.01
     6    8.3e-05    0.00017    0.0033    0.0083
     7    7.1e-05    0.00014    0.0029    0.0071
     8    6.3e-05    0.00013    0.0025    0.0063
     9    5.6e-05    0.00011    0.0022    0.0056
    10      5e-05     0.0001     0.002     0.005
    11    4.5e-05    9.1e-05    0.0018    0.0045
    12    4.2e-05    8.3e-05    0.0017    0.0042
    13    3.8e-05    7.7e-05    0.0015    0.0038
    14    3.6e-05    7.1e-05    0.0014    0.0036
    15    3.3e-05    6.7e-05    0.0013    0.0033
    16    3.1e-05    6.3e-05    0.0013    0.0031
    17    2.9e-05    5.9e-05    0.0012    0.0029
    18    2.8e-05    5.6e-05    0.0011    0.0028
    19    2.6e-05    5.3e-05    0.0011    0.0026
    20    2.5e-05      5e-05     0.001    0.0025
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are assigning a string to a double-float array. It looks like MATLAB automatically converts the string to a double to store it there. Thus, your formatting gets lost:

```
>> sprintf("%.1e", 1/1000)
ans = 
    "1.0e-03"
>> a=0;
>> a(1) = sprintf("%.1e", 1/1000)
a =
   1.0000e-03
>> class(a)
ans =
    'double'
```

Instead, use a string array:

```
a = strings(19,1);
%...
   a(i-1) = sprintf("%.1e", w);
```

---

I'm not used to the new strings, and this behavior surprises me. Assigning a number to a string converts the number to a string, and assigning the string to a number converts it back to a number. This does not happen with the "old-fashioned" char arrays:

```
>> a=0;
>> a(1) = sprintf('%.1e', 1/1000);
Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements.
```

When using char arrays, store them in a cell array:

```
a = cell(19,1);
%...
   a{i-1} = sprintf('%.1e', w);
```

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks. What would be best way to convert the formatted string back to a float just so the table doesn't display quotation marks

Comment: @alexanderd5398: Good question. That's a whole different can of worms, I think. I'm not too familiar with tables, I'm afraid, and I think you need to look into setting up the table so it displays numbers in the way you want them to be. Either that, or write your own table display function that uses `sprintf` as above and prints all your data as you want to see it.

Comment: Alright thanks. I guess I'll just deal with the quotation marks since I don't really want to get into building my own table function.

Comment: @alexanderd5398: [This](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/346855-how-to-round-number-in-table-to-two-digit-number) seems to imply that it is not possible to change how `table` formats its output. They suggest rounding the numbers you put into the table, but I don't think that will give you only one decimal place.

Comment: Yeah I looked at that, but since some of the numbers I am displaying are very small while some are around 0.1, the small numbers just displayed as zeros. I could never get a consistent format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "fprintf":

```
>> fprintf("%.1f\n", pi)
3.1
```

To show more or less digits just adjust the number after the dot.

Comment: I need scientific notation. So `3.1e+00`. But the problem is more that I can't make the format consistent in a table.